# Yocto image Building fails

Tags: docker, yocto, quectel

currently i'm trying to build a yocto image for a sc20 from quectel and i'm getting this error.

[Yocto error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX8qp.jpg)

file  msm8990.inc has RECOVERYFS_SIZE_EXT4='268435456'

how can i handle this type of issue?

here is a complete log

```
ERROR: machine-recovery-image-1.0-r0 do_makesystem: Function failed: do_makesystem (log file is located at /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_makesystem.3590122)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_makesystem.3590122
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_makesystem
| error: ext4_allocate_best_fit_partial: failed to allocate 74 blocks, out of space?
| fs_config_file: (none)
| No fs_config applied as no fsconfig.conf file passed using -C option.
| Creating filesystem with parameters:
|     Size: 268435456
|     Block size: 4096
|     Blocks per group: 32768
|     Inodes per group: 8192
|     Inode size: 256
|     Journal blocks: 1024
|     Label:
|     Blocks: 65536
|     Block groups: 2
|     Reserved block group size: 15
| WARNING: /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_makesystem.3590122:1 exit 1 from 'make_ext4fs -s -a / -S /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/selinux/mls/contexts/files/file_contexts -l 268435456 /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/deploy/images/msm8909-quec-smart/msm8909-recoveryfs.ext4 /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/rootfs'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_makesystem (log file is located at /opt/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/msm8909-oe-linux-gnueabi/machine-recovery-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_makesystem.3590122)
ERROR: Task (/opt/poky/meta-qti-bsp/recipes-products/images/machine-recovery-image.bb:do_makesystem) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 7550 tasks of which 7547 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /opt/poky/meta-qti-bsp/recipes-products/images/machine-recovery-image.bb:do_makesystem
Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
/opt/poky/build
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> error: ext4_allocate_best_fit_partial: failed to allocate 74 blocks,
> out of space?

The error is related to the size of the image. Your system files tree is bigger than your image size.

To solve the problem you need to increase the root filesystem partition size:

*make menuconfig* -> *Target Images* -> *Root filesystem partition size (in MB)*

Comment: hi kluszon, i cannot acces to make menuconfig. and i tried to change filesystem size but problem persist. i'm building with docker image and bitbake

Comment: The problem for sure is with image size. I don't have experience with building docker images, but it works for normal yocto linux os. You need to search how to do it for docker.